# Deploy to Tomcat using Maven

Tags: maven, tomcat

I am working through online examples to deploy my web service (Spring Boot) using Maven. In development I was running 'mvn spring-boot:run' to run an embedded Tomcat server however now I want to run it on my actual Tomcat server and not the embedded one.

However when I run 'mvn install tomcat7:deploy' it installs it in a Maven repository. I have followed about 4 different online examples but it always does the same thing. Instead, I am expecting it to my apache-tomcat-9.0.14 directory.

Do I need to copy manually the files from Maven repository to my apache tomcat directories?

Thank you.. any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `maven-war-plugin`, then we can instruct maven to copy the WAR to the desired location within the tomcat.

```
<build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
           <outputDirectory><!-- Webapps directory location inside the Tomcat. Something like D:\ProgramFiles\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\webapps--></outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If your dependencies are marked with the scope of `provided`, then these libraries need to be copied to `lib` directory inside the tomcat manually or you can use the `maven-dependency-plugin`.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${tomcat.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
          <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
          <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

It is always a better practice to have a separate directory for external libraries. Something like `lib\ext\` inside the tomact.
This directory then should be listed in `catalina.properties` in the `\conf` directory inside the tomcat.

```
common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib","${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,"${catalina.home}/lib/ext","${catalina.home}/lib/ext/*.jar""
```

If your dependencies are of the scope `compile` or not specified a scope ( That is by default they have a scope of compile ). Then, they will be bundled with the WAR file, hence no need to copy them to the above mentioned directory.

Above will help you to deploy your WAR into an external tomcat. Once WAR file is copied over to webapps dir and required jar files [ if any ] are copied to the lib [ or ext ] directory, You are good to go and start the tomcat with `bin\startup.bat` in Windows or 'bin\startup.sh' in Linux system

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you very much.

Comment: @scoobyroo Kindly mark the answer as an accepted answer if this helped to solve your issue. :)

Comment: I did that but as I am a newbie it records it but does not show it.